# WkWebView sometimes loses the session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, session-cookies, wkwebview

I have a Ruby on Rails backend web application. I use iOS application as a web client (WKWebView) written in swift. The authentication token is stored as a session cookies variable on the backend:

`session['token'] = generate_token`

The problem is that accidentally this session variable is lost and the flow is redirected to login page. 
The WKWebView is not closed, just used to process HTTP requests.
I'm not able to figure out, why this accidentally happens.

Comment: Are you storing token in the db?

Comment: Yes I'm. Before processing every request I compare the token in DB with session['token'].

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using just a webView and not default Safari browser meaning you are making your custom browser hence you are responsible to handle things like caching your token for the current session. My suggestion, if you want the token to be stored and used only once then create a variable something like

```
let accessToken = "your json web token"
```

Then pass it as a header when making a request to your server.

If you want to maintain access then you might want to save your token in keyChain or userDefaults depending on the level of security.

**Navigation and other user interactions**

As I mentioned, using wkwebView meaning you are making your own browser so you have to detect subsequent requests as the user interact with your web pages. For navigation, you have to use [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate) methods.

If **WKNavigationDelegate** does not solve your problem then you have to make use of Javascript events ie.. post an event when user visit a certain page and use [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler) to respond to those events by passing the acess token etc..

Comment: I can do it in the first request loaded in WKWebView. But what about another requests, which are called after clicking to http links on the web sites?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include more detail on how to handle such situations.

Comment: I am working on webView, I just found this article https://novemberfive.co/blog/WKWebView-redirect-with-cookies . Maybe it will be useful to you too. 
@PeterBalogh